# How can I make my HTC One stop vibrating on notifications, but still make noise?

Tags: vibration, htc-one

My HTC One vibrates every darn time the notification sound comes on, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to stop. I have "vibrate on calls" unticked in the setting, under sound, and it still does it. This was never a problem before that system update a little while ago.

I am seriously so mad right now.

Help?

Comment: Same occurs on HTC U Play... I'm equally annoyed at this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I too went in to Settings > Accessibility and turn off for reminder of notifications. That fixed it for me. (For HTC 826)

Comment: I see no reason to add this answer since the content is already covered in [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/100227/96277).

Answer (score 0):

To remove vibration you should 
Settings > Sound > deselect the vibration box

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings → Accessibility and untick the box for reminder of notifications. That might fix it.